# Placeholder in string-array in strings.xml

Tags: android, arrays, xml, string, kotlin

I'm trying to have placeholder(same value will be used in every item) in a string array.

```
<string-array name="distance_rating_labels">
    <item>&lt; 5 %s</item>
    <item>&lt; 10 %s</item>
    <item>&lt; 15 %s</item>
</string-array>
```

Here I want to return `< 5 km` or `< 5 miles` based on the distance metric passed at runtime.
I know it can be done by splitting them to strings and passing the distance metric at runtime like

```
<string name="less_than_5">&lt; 5 %s</string>
```

But is it possible to do it with an array?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i would be very surprised if this is really a new question, seems impossible that nobody has asked this yet, but it's very interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code of `Resources.getString(id, formatArgs)` (the method `Context.getString(id, formatArgs)` is proxying to) looks as follows:

```
@NonNull
public String getString(@StringRes int id, Object... formatArgs) throws NotFoundException {
    final String raw = getString(id);
    return String.format(mResourcesImpl.getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0), raw,
            formatArgs);
}
```

Thus, you can do something like this:

```
val resources = context.resources
val rawLabels = resources.getStringArray(R.array.distance_rating_labels)
val currentLocale = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    resources.configuration.locales.get(0)
else
    resources.configuration.locale
val distance = String.format(currentLocale, rawLabels[index], arg)
```

Comment: Never post pictures of text, because they are not searchable.

Comment: @ValerijDobler ok, no problem, I just didn't think this specific piece is relevant for search, as the solution itself is a text